# Applying validation on a field on an existing item based on the value of another field

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Scenario: I have many SharePoint items that get created by an offline process.  So the list items *already exist*, they are not new when the user is notified about them.  I have a choice field called Status, and a multiline text field called Comments.  The business requirement is to force the user to enter comments if they change the default value of the Status field.  I could do this with an event receiver, but our users hate the "Something went wrong" page, plus these days users just like field validation done while they are on the page.  I would greatly appreciate any detailed advice, especially something including a code "example".  Remember, I have to compare deltas here, only validate comments IF the Status changed.

Comment: Try to use custom form with CustomValidator for You content type.